# Linking span to parent span using trace_id and span_id

Tags: python, go, open-telemetry

I have a go process which starts a parent span up. I then call an export function to save the span_id and trace_id in a json file.

```
tracer := otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("")
_, span := tracer.Start(ctx, "parent span name")
exportSpanContextToJSON(span)
...
defer span.End()
```

The go process eventually runs a python script. I need to start spans in the python process that are all children of the parent span from go.

The python script is not so straightforward.

I am instantiating a class `MainStreamEngine` that creates the tracer. It has a function called `new_stream` that creates an instance of the `ChildStream`, which takes stuff in from the `MainStreamEngine`. It looks something like this:

```
class MainStreamEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        resource = Resource(attributes={
            "service.name": "python_service"
        })
        trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider(resource=resource))
        self.tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
        otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(
            endpoint="http://localhost:4317", insecure=True)
        span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter)
        trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)
        self.span_context = trace.SpanContext(
            is_remote=True,
            span_id=int(span_ctx_from_json["spanId"], 16)),
            trace_id=int(span_ctx_from_json["traceId"], 16))

    def new_stream(self):
        stream = ChildStream(self.tracer, self.span_context)

class ChildStream:
    def __init__(self, tracer, span_context):
        self.tracer = tracer
        ctx = trace.set_span_in_context(trace.NonRecordingSpan(span_context))
        self.tracing_span = tracer.start_span(self.name, ctx)

    def close(self):
        self.tracing_span.close()
```

The issue is that the spans in the python process are being created with their own `trace_id` and not under the `trace_id` from the go process (and I also need them to be child spans of the span created in go).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using *explicit* span context passing between `MainStreamEngine` and `ChildStream`. It isn't clear how you are passing the span context downstream in `ChildStream`, but since you call [`tracer.start_span`](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/trace.html#opentelemetry.trace.Tracer.start_span) to create your span, you will also need make sure that all of your immediate downstream spans use *explicit* span context passing as well by passing `tracing_span` (or more specifically [`tracing_span.get_span_context()`](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/trace.html#opentelemetry.trace.Tracer.start_span)) downstream.

If any of your immediate downstream spans are created using *implicit* span context passing, they won't know about the span from `ChildStream` because it was never set as the *current* span. If you want to use *implicit* span context passing, you'll want to use [`tracer.start_as_current_span`](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/trace.html#opentelemetry.trace.Tracer.start_as_current_span) to start the span in `ChildStream`.

Further if you want to use *implicit* span context passing throughout, you can use [`context.attach(ctx)`](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/context.html#opentelemetry.context.attach) in `MainStreamEngine.__init__` and then you don't need to pass `self.span_context` when you create `ChildStream`. See the last few lines of the [Manually setting span context in this cookbook](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/python/cookbook/#manually-setting-span-context) for an example.

Lastly, if you want to simplify context propagation between Go and Python and want to avoid writing the JSON file, I have a small Python module that creates a span for the lifetime of the Python process and links it to a parent span if a TRACEPARENT environment variable is set, if any (following the informal pattern [mentioned here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/issues/740)). Let me know if that might be useful and I can cleanup the code and share it.